# How i install Magento 2.4.3p2 using composer?

Tags: installation, composer, magento2.4.3

I am new in magento.
so, please give me a hint how to install magento 2.4.3p2 using composer with sample data

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link :

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html

But you have to install all prerequisites of the Magento

Answer (score 0):

Example - Security patch

Security patches contain security fixes only. They are designed to make the upgrade process faster and easier.

Security patches use the Composer naming convention 2.4.3-px. Use Composer to specify a patch. For example, to download the Adobe Commerce 2.4.3-p1 metapackage:

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition=2.4.3-p2 <install-directory-name>`

from https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento Open Source**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ 
magento/project-community-edition:2.4.3-p2
```

**For Adobe Commerce (Enterprise)**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ 
magento/project-enterprise-edition:2.4.5
```